# mime file type validation on wiki

Tags: mediawiki

I am running a private MediaWiki version 1.35.1 on Ubuntu Mate.  I added a new file extension, `'cev'`, to my `LocalSettings.php` but when I try to upload a file it gives me this message:

[image]

So, I went to [this page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:MIME_type_detection) and down under **Mime Type validation** it says there are 2 files in the Mediawiki `includes` folder that can be customized to allow/ignore that error.  Well, a "broken link" note on that page seems to indicate that the file `MimeMap.php` under `/includes/libs/mime` is the one to modify.

So, how do i modify `MimeMap.php` so it either ignores `.CEV` files or otherwise accepts them without the error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To support extra mime types for uploads on your wiki, you can use the [MimeMagicInit hook](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/MimeMagicInit) since MediaWiki 1.24.

For example, to recognise `.md` files as `text/plain` for Markdown:

```php
// Recognise the extension
$wgHooks['MimeMagicInit'][] = function ( MimeAnalyzer $mime ) {
    $mime->addExtraTypes( 'text/plain md' );
};

// Allow it for new uploads
$wgFileExtensions[] = 'md';
```

I've also updated the [MIME type detection](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:MIME_type_detection) page on mediawiki.org with this, and more information.

Answer (score 1):

Did you already try
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Topic:Ps6zng4e6b00rsor

```php
$wgVerifyMimeType = false;
$wgStrictFileExtensions = false;
$wgCheckFileExtensions = false;
```

There is also a strange workaround for some file types:

```php
$wgAllowJavaUploads = true; // Solves problem with Office 2007 and newer files (docx, xlsx, etc.)
```

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgAllowJavaUploads

seems to help in some cases.

Comment: Hi @wolfgangfahl, no because that would defeat all MIME type checking (as I understand it) and I just want to get past this issue with this one file type (`.CEV`).

Comment: @relayman357 makes absolute sense - I'd appreciate if you file a phabricator task and official feature request for being able to have mime type checking exception or user defined checks.

Comment: Ok, @wolfgangfahl, I believe i have successfully created the phabricator task: https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T281069